# Implement Client and Server model which communicate via TCP protocol using Boost framework

Tags: c++, server, tcp, client, boost-asio

I have to try to implement the following details, can you please let me know what is wrong with the implementation and how the right one implemented.

1. Client and Server should be able exchange 4-byte messages via TCP protocol.Client generate random unsigned number in range [10^6, 10^8) and sends it to Server.

2)Server has a SUM resource which represents a calculation result of processed messages received from Clients.
On receiving random unsigned number in range [10^6, 10^8) from client, Server adds this number to SUM if it is an even number and subtracts otherwise.

3)Server continuously listens for new connections and is capable of handling multiple clients at the same time.

4)If an absolute value of SUM in the console did not exceed MAX UINT 32 value after the operation,
The server prints current all connections and sends an acknowledgment message with MAX UINT 32 value.
otherwise, SUM exceeds MAX UINT 32 value, closes all connections, and exits.

5)If the Client receives the acknowledgment, it starts a 50ms timer and repeats the generation/sending sequence, until Server closes the connection.

```
=======================client.cpp===================================

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include<boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{ //  static used for efficiency, so we only calculate this value once
    static constexpr uint_32 fraction { 1.0 / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) }; 
    // evenly distribute the random number across our range
    return min + static_cast<int>((max - min + 1) * (std::rand() * fraction));
}

int main() {
     boost::asio::io_service io_service;
//socket creation
     tcp::socket socket(io_service);
//connection
     socket.connect( tcp::endpoint( boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.9"), 4321 ));
// request/message from client
     const string msg = "Hello from Client!\n";
     unsigned long int number;
     number = getRandomNumber(10^6, 10^8);

     boost::system::error_code error;
     boost::asio::write( socket, boost::asio::buffer(number), error );
     if( !error ) {
        cout << "Client sent hello message!" << endl;
     }
     else {
        cout << "send failed: " << error.message() << endl;
     }
 // getting response from server
    boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;
    boost::asio::read(socket, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);

    if( error && error != boost::asio::error::eof ) {
        cout << "receive failed: " << error.message() << endl;

        sleep_for_a_while(50);
    }
    else {
        const char* data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(receive_buffer.data());
        cout << data << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

=============================server.cpp===========================
    
unsigned long int& read_(tcp::socket & socket, unsigned long int& sum) {

       boost::asio::streambuf buf;
       boost::asio::read_until( socket, buf, "\n" );
       unsigned long int data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
       if(data % 2 == 1) {
            sum = sum - data;
       } else {
            sum = sum + data;
        }
       return data;
}

//send  msg to client
void send_(tcp::socket & socket, const string& message) {

       const string msg = message + "\n";
       boost::asio::write( socket, boost::asio::buffer(message) );
}


//main to init server
int main() {

    unsigned long int sum = 0;
//io_service object is needed whenever a program is using asio
      boost::asio::io_service io_service;
//listen for new connection requested by the client
      tcp::acceptor acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 4321 ));// IP-ipv4 and port-1234
//socket creation
      tcp::socket socket_(io_service);
//waiting for connection
      acceptor_.accept(socket_);
//read operation //write operation
      unsigned long int SUM  = read_(socket_, &sum);

      if(abs(SUM) <= 4294967295) { //2^32
        cout << "SUM = " << SUM<< endl;
        send_(socket_, "Acknowledgment from Server with MAX UINT 32 value-4294967295");
      } else {
          socket_.close();
      }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is? SO is not a code writing service

Comment: The server sample is missing one or more lines before "// creating the pointer
  static pointer"

Comment: Thanks, it was just an empty body, How to put a 50ms timer in the client and repeats sending sequence until Server closes the connection, using  TIME_WAIT, or shutdownOutput().

Comment: That's a different question with no relation to the code shown. The reason we are urging you to write a more specific question is because right now it strongly seems like you copy-pasted some unrelated example and dumped your home-work requirements with them in the hopes someone will do it for you. I suggest you start doing the changes, and when you have problems along the way, ask about _those_ specific questions.

Comment: yes, I have recently started learning socket programming, got this task to finish, So looking fro someone which deep knowledge to can point ut write direction. I have made changes n the code /finish according to the requirement. Can you please review, and suggest.

Comment: I've retracted my close cute and will give it a look later